# Hero slider with wide image and animations on it to work with mobile

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs, css-animations

I'm working on side project and the client want from me to create hero for full screen and should be scrollable horizontally, you can click on the image and swipe from left to right and from right to left.

So from beginning, I have a huge image 5000px x 2000px and eg. on full hd monitor I need to show the image center and user can swipe in horizontal to see the rest of the content.

Should be responsive also for the mobile that height of the hero will be always 100vh and width of that image will calculate proportionally.

here is the video how it should look like:

https://drive.google.com/file/d/14V0CEuWvapHBxI5ZQ1tc33IiYMDWZJdZ/view?usp=sharing

also is another challenge, that animations should be in this slider, got  sequence from Designer to animate, and I need to put that animation in absolute position, for example fire animation.

there is a figma to play with desktop version: https://www.figma.com/proto/87RAbQap8Yeekp0oEsHnti/Dogin-Hood-Prototype?page-id=314%3A163&type=design&node-id=314-172&viewport=834%2C623%2C0.22&t=O4Q5e267S4aTUQuB-1&scaling=contain&starting-point-node-id=314%3A164&fbclid=IwAR0_CZFbiYo-DYsY5WL3kJTyltH3lOdEEwimeLYQbdLklxXHENa3XpmWe-Y

mobile version:
https://www.figma.com/proto/87RAbQap8Yeekp0oEsHnti/Dogin-Hood-Prototype?page-id=314%3A118&type=design&node-id=314-140&viewport=869%2C499%2C0.24&t=TEd6JBiyguH4tawi-1&scaling=scale-down&starting-point-node-id=314%3A132&fbclid=IwAR0zLZhdzuwithXF9Xx-RRTpHUzeKop-JE_EFBtAeub5ipXNEaL-ulXfIrw

I'm wondering to use library https://material-you-slider.uiinitiative.com/ but hmm, calculate what is the width of the window and split the image to multiple part?

Also was wondering if I can accomplish it with only CSS but it wasn't good choice.

another thing is that the whole assets for page has 100mb, so is a chance to create preloader in React to load all assets and then show the page? With dom-routing?

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

I did with css solution to have horizontal scroll:

```
<div className={styles.root} ref={target} style={{width: widthRoot}}>
            <div
                id="background"
                style={{
                    backgroundSize: `${widthRoot} 100vh`,
                    backgroundImage: `url(${BackgroundImage})`,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                }}
                className={styles.layer}
            >
                <Campfire id="campfire"/>
                <Cave id='cave' />
                <Chest id='chest' />
                <Fish id='fish' />
            </div>
            <div
                style={{
                    backgroundSize: `${widthRoot} 100vh`,
                    backgroundImage: `url(${CoverImage})`,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                }}
                className={styles.layer}
            />

            <div
                style={{
                    backgroundSize: `${widthRoot} 100vh`,
                    backgroundImage: `url(${ForegroundImage})`,
                    left: 0,
                    right: 0,
                }}
                className={styles.layer}
            >
                <div id='cave-button' className={styles.button} onClick={caveStart}/>
                <div id='chest-button' className={styles.button} onClick={chestStart}/>
                <div id='fish-button' className={styles.button} onClick={fishStart}/>
            </div>
        </div>
```

and for resizing I have useEffect:

```
 useEffect(() => {
        if (!loading) {
            setTimeout(() => {
                const setDimensions = () => {
                    const container = document.getElementById('background');
                    const originalImgBounds = container.getBoundingClientRect();
                    let newZoomedWidth = originalImgBounds.height * 5500 / 3094;
                    if (window.innerWidth > newZoomedWidth) {
                        newZoomedWidth = window.innerWidth;
                    }
                    setWidthRoot(`${newZoomedWidth}px`);
                    calculatePosition('campfire', container, {
                        width: 635,
                        height: 620,
                        x: 2768,
                        y: 1326,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);
                    calculatePosition('cave', container, {
                        width: 469,
                        height: 362,
                        x: 2662,
                        y: 834,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);
                    calculatePosition('chest', container, {
                        width: 1710,
                        height: 1293,
                        x: 0,
                        y: 1020,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);
                    calculatePosition('fish', container, {
                        width: 2143,
                        height: 779,
                        x: 1609,
                        y: 2252,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);


                    calculatePosition('cave-button', container, {
                        width: 469,
                        height: 362,
                        x: 2662,
                        y: 834,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);
                    calculatePosition('chest-button', container, {
                        width: 1710,
                        height: 1293,
                        x: 0,
                        y: 1020,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);
                    calculatePosition('fish-button', container, {
                        width: 2143,
                        height: 779,
                        x: 1609,
                        y: 2252,
                    }, newZoomedWidth);

                }
                setDimensions();
                window.addEventListener('load', setDimensions);
                window.addEventListener('resize', setDimensions);

            }, 10);
        }
```

and to calculate exact position for animations and scale it:

```
const backgroundImageWidth = 5500;
const backgroundImageHeight = 3094;

export function calculatePosition(name: string, container: any, details: PositionDetails) {
    const {
        width: desiredImageWidth,
        height: desiredImageHeight,
        x: desiredX,
        y: desiredY,
    } = details

    const image = document.getElementById(name);

    // Calculate the scale factor for the image based on the background size
    const scaleX = container.clientWidth / backgroundImageWidth;
    const scaleY = container.clientHeight / backgroundImageHeight;

    // Calculate the actual position for the image based on the desired position
    const actualX = desiredX * scaleX;
    const actualY = desiredY * scaleY;

    // Calculate the actual dimensions for the image based on the desired dimensions
    const actualImageWidth = desiredImageWidth * scaleX;
    const actualImageHeight = desiredImageHeight * scaleY;

    // Set the styles for the image
    image!.style.width = `${actualImageWidth}px`;
    image!.style.height = `${actualImageHeight}px`;
    image!.style.top = `${actualY}px`;
    image!.style.left = `${actualX}px`;

}
```

if anyone would like to see the whole project, dm me and send invite to repo.